# Not able to send email to other domains

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have some code that can only work with *my* SMTP host domains but not others. It seems to send, but it doesn't actually send anything and it also doesn't throw any exceptions.

```
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
mailClient.Port = 587;

mailClient.EnableSsl = false;
mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
mailClient.Host = "mail.smtpserver.com";



System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@smtpserver.com", "password");

mailClient.Credentials = cred;



MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.From = new MailAddress("mail@smtpserver.com");
message.To.Add("mail@remotedomain.com");

message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "Body";

mailClient.Timeout = 200000;

mailClient.Send(message);
```

I think the problem is not checking NetworkCredential...

Comment: is the port correct for your mailserver?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to send a testing mail with the "other" smtp server using telnet to make sure it works.

your smtp port is not the default one so maybe it is blocked by your firewall.

Comment: Actually I changed 2 other networks with 2 different firewall rules, But is is same that no errors give. If I send mail to "user@stmpserver.com" it works, but others it isn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're using port 587 then that is SSL secured SMTP - so you need to change your code so that uses it when establishing the connection:

```
mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
```